# How to find remainder of a double in C? Modulo only works for integers

Tags: c, modulo

This is what I've found so far online,

```
int main(void)
{
    long a = 12345;
    int b = 10;

    int remain = a - (a / b) * b;
    printf("%i\n", remain);
}
```

First I wonder how the formula works. Maybe i cant do math, but the priority of operations here seems a bit odd. If i run this code the expected answer of 5 is printed. But I dont get how (a / b) * b doesn't cancel out to 'a' leading to a - a = 0.

Now, this only works for int and long, as soon as double are involved it doesn't work anymore. Anyone might tell me why? Is there an alternative to modulo that works for double?

Also I'm not sure if i understand up to what value a long can go, i found online that the upper limit was 2147483647 but when i input bigger numbers such as the one in 'a' the code runs without any issue up to a certain point...

Thanks for your help I'm new to coding and trying to learn!

Comment: There's an [`fmod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) function in the standard library.  Or are you asking how you'd implement it?

Comment: First, there are no doubles in your code.  In C, a `double` is a floating point value.  Your code is doing only integer math.  Second, when two integers are divided in C, the result is an integer, not a floating point value.  So `123 / 10` is `12`, and `(123 / 10) * 10` is `120`.  The divide and the multiply don't cancel out when the divide result is truncated to an integer.

Comment: You've declared `a` as a long, which is apparently 64-bits on your system. You can check with `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a))`. If the output is 8, then a `long` is 8 bytes, which is 64 bits. The `2147...` value is the upper limit for a 32-bit signed number.

Comment: The maximum value of a `long` is given by `LONG_MAX`, [which is defined in `<limits.h>`.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1)

Comment: Kind of an aside, but what does "remainder" or "modulo" even mean when talking about floats (real numbers)?

Comment: @pmacfarlane A circle's circumference is 2*pi radians. Let's call that a "real"... Compute the sin (or cos) of a value like `sin( toRadians( 375 ) )` (where 375 is an angle in degrees), Phase shifting, for example, can result in values that benefit from a `modulo` function for "real numbers"......

Comment: @Fe2O3 I get angles. A phase shift is not the result of a division, but the result of a subtraction. We're way OT here - peace out.

Comment: @pmacfarlane: There are several ways to define the remainder of *x* modulo *y*, even for integers, based on whether we want the remainder to be in [0, |y|), (−½|y|, +½|y|], or some variation on those. Once the desired interval is chosen, the remainder is *x* − *ny*, where *n* is chosen to put *x* − *ny* in the desired interval. For example, *n* might be floor(*x* / *y*) or round(*x* / *y*), and that would not depend on whether *x* and *y* were integers or not.

Comment: Supplement to the immediately above comment: *n* is an integer.

Comment: The expression `a - (a / b) * b` is equivalent to using the modulo operator: `a % b`.

Comment: @nielsen I don't understand how it is equivalent... Do you know?

Comment: @goldensnub The result is identical (for integers `a` and `b`).

Answer (score 4):

Given two `double` finite numbers `x` and `y`, with `y` not equal to zero, `fmod(x, y)` produces the remainder of `x` when divided by `y`. Specifically, it returns `x` − *n*`y`, where *n* is chosen so that `x` − *n*`y` has the same sign as `x` and is smaller in magnitude than `y`. (So, if `x` is positive, 0 ≤ `fmod(x, y)` < `x`, and, if `x` is negative, `x` < `fmod(x, y)` ≤ 0.)

`fmod` is declared in `<math.h>`.

A properly implemented `fmod` returns an exact result; there is no floating-point error, since the specified result is always representable.

The C standard also specifies `remquo` to return the remainder and some low bits (at least three) of the quotient *n* and `remainder` with a variation on the definition of the remainder. It also specifies variants of these functions for `float` and `long double`.

Answer (score -2):

Naive implementation. Limited range. Adds additional floating point imprecisions (as it does some arithmetic)

```
double naivemod(double x)
{
    return x - (long long)x;
}


int main(void)
{
    printf("%.50f\n", naivemod(345345.567567756));
    printf("%.50f\n", naivemod(.0));
    printf("%.50f\n", naivemod(10.5));
    printf("%.50f\n", naivemod(-10.0/3));
    
}
```